# Bad search filter - postfix, OpenLDAP, Saslauthd

Tags: debian, postfix, ldap, sasl

I am trying to setup a mail server on Debian Jessie and have come across a problem that's doing my head in.

When trying to access OpenLDAP through saslauthd via the command

```
testsaslauthd -u user1 -p user1pw -f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux
```

I get the following error in auth.log

```
Apr 17 10:36:50 debmailserv saslauthd[1661]: user ldap_search_st() failed: Bad search filter
Apr 17 10:36:50 debmailserv saslauthd[1661]: Retrying authentication
Apr 17 10:36:50 debmailserv saslauthd[1661]: user ldap_search_st() failed: Bad search filter
Apr 17 10:36:50 debmailserv saslauthd[1661]: Authentication failed for user1: Retry condition (ldap server connection reset or broken) (-3)
Apr 17 10:36:50 debmailserv saslauthd[1661]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=user1] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=ldap] [reason=Unknown]
```

But if i use the same search filter used in saslauthd.conf using the following ldapsearch it works fine.

```
ldapsearch -D "uid=saslauthd,ou=services,dc=example,dc=com" -w saslauthdpw \
  -p 389 -h 127.0.0.1 -b "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" \
  -s sub "(&(uid=user1)(mailEnabled=TRUE))"
```

My saslauthd.conf looks like this

```
# Server
ldap_servers: ldap://127.0.0.1/

# Identity
ldap_bind_dn: uid=saslauthd,ou=services,dc=example,dc=com
ldap_bind_pw: saslauthdpw
ldap_auth_method: bind

# Connection
ldap_version: 3
ldap_timeout: 10
ldap_time_limit: 10
ldap_referrals: yes

# Search
ldap_scope: sub
ldap_search_base: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
ldap_filter: (&(uid=%u)(mailEnabled=TRUE))

# SSL
ldap_ssl: no
ldap_starttls: no
```

If I comment out the ldap_filter then the testsaslauth works fine.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately `saslauthd` does not provide further details to see what is actually passed to the `ldap_search_st` function as `filter` argument. The simplest possibility would by probably to run it under `gdb` to see what are the actual arguments after expansions and whatever is evaluated further. Otherwise I don't see any problem there.

Comment: Is your LDAP server a ActiveDirectory? Try to set ldap_referrals to no

Comment: @Izac I am using OpenLDAP. I tried with both `ldap_referrals` to yes and no and the same result

Comment: @Jakuje It seems that `testsaslauthd` does not have any debugging built in to the executable. Unfortunately I'm not too proficient in the linux environment so I might try again from a fresh system to see if some other config is interfering with `saslathd`.

Comment: Is your filter working with ldapsearch on the command line?

Comment: @Izac When I run `ldapsearch` with the arguments stated above it works fine.
I have tried again from a fresh system but the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error today.
By using wireshark to examine the conversation between saslauthd and the LDAP server I was able to determine two things that might help you...

1. The default filter appears to be (uid=%u)
2. The query from saslauthd restricts the size of the result to 1 record.

In my case a search for uid=fred was returning two records from the LDAP server.